# Error with DefaultOAuthProvider in Android

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

Well, I'm trying to get Twitter to work on a basic Android application, it works just fine in my 2.3.6 but as I try to use 4.0+ it fails trying to authenticate.. Here is my small little code

```
private OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(REQUEST_URL, ACCESS_URL, AUTHORIZE_URL);
private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setContentView(webview);
    try {
        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL); 
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
            @Override  
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  {  
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                    try {
                        provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);
                        String claveUsuario = consumer.getToken();
                        String secretoUsuario = consumer.getTokenSecret();
                        HttpParameters params1 = provider.getResponseParameters();
                        String userName = params1.getFirst("screen_name");
                        SharedPreferences settings = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCIAS, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("clave_usuario", claveUsuario);
                        editor.putString("secreto_usuario", secretoUsuario);
                        editor.putString("nombre_usuario", userName);
                        editor.commit();
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        String origen = intent.getExtras().getString("Origen");
                        if (origen != null) {
                            if (origen.equals("Twittear")) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(AutenticarTwitter.this, Twittear.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                            else if (origen.equals("Autores")) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(AutenticarTwitter.this, Autores.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(AutenticarTwitter.this, Ajustes.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) {}                
                }
            }   
        });  
        webview.loadUrl(authUrl);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

And as I said, it works just fine in Android 2.3.6, but when it comes to 4.0+ it fails in line:

```
String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
```

And I've unsuccesfully tried to fix this. My logcat is something like:

```
04-29 22:37:39.256: W/System.err(784): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
04-29 22:37:39.256: W/System.err(784):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
04-29 22:37:39.256: W/System.err(784):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
04-29 22:37:39.256: W/System.err(784):  at com.example.twitter.OAuthAccessTokenActivity.onResume(OAuthAccessTokenActivity.java:43)
04-29 22:37:39.256: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
04-29 22:37:39.276: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
04-29 22:37:39.276: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
04-29 22:37:39.276: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
04-29 22:37:39.276: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
04-29 22:37:39.296: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-29 22:37:39.296: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-29 22:37:39.296: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 22:37:39.296: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Everythings seems ok but function retrieveRequestToken() throws 'OAuthCommunicationException' exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779186/everythings-seems-ok-but-function-retrieverequesttoken-throws-oauthcommunicat)?

My guess is your code performs some kind of networking operation in the main thread.
If you are targeting the Honeycomb or higher (3.0+), you cannot perform a networking operation on the main thread.

Please see [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) for more info.

Basically, you have to use AsyncTask and move your networking stuffs into doInBackground method. Below's the code. Just to give you the idea.

```
class NetworkingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL); 
        ...
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, no, I had not seen that, :S, I will give it a try.